# Shorter way to traverse nested record with Maybe

Tags: haskell, haskell-lens, lenses

Is there a shorter/cleaner way of writing the following snippet of code:

```
fromMaybe "" $ fmap (^. fullName) (bi ^. bookerContact)
```

Here `bi ^. bookerContact` may result in a `Maybe Contact` record, which is why `^. fullName` needs to be fmapped. After the nested traversal, if we end up with a `Nothing` we use `fromMaybe ""` to default it to a blank string.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

A simple way of tidying it is using `maybe` instead of the `fromMaybe`/`fmap` combo:

```
maybe "" (^. fullName) (bi ^. bookerContact)
```

You can also introduce the `_Just` prism to express all of the drilling down as a single optic:

```
fromMaybe "" (bi ^? bookerContact . _Just . fullName)
```

Note that we have switched from `(^.)` to `(^?)`. That reflects how adding `_Just` to the chain changes what used to be a lens (and reach exactly one target) into a traversal (which might reach no targets).

---

It is also possible to take advantage of `Text` being a monoid and use `fold` from `Data.Foldable`...

```
fold (bi ^? bookerContact . _Just . fullName)
```

... or [`foldOf`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/lens-4.15.1/docs/Control-Lens-Fold.html#v:foldOf), if you prefer the *lens* spelling:

```
foldOf (bookerContact . _Just . fullName) bi
```

As [the docs](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/lens-5.0.1/docs/Control-Lens-Fold.html#v:foldOf) point out, `foldOf` is equivalent to `(^.)` ([which is essentially `view` specialised to `(->)`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/lens-5.0.1/docs/Control-Lens-Getter.html#v:-94-.)), so this will also work, by folding the `Maybe Text`:

```
bi ^. bookerContact . _Just . fullName
```

Comment: Hmm... I'm not clear how the type of `bi ^. bookerContact._Just.fullName` is coming out to be `Text`. Shouldn't it be `Maybe Text`?

Comment: `^. _Just` over a `Maybe Text` results in a `""` However `^. _Just` over a `Maybe Int` results in the following error -- `No instance for (Monoid Int) arising from a use of ‘_Just’` Is it possible to traverse over a `Maybe` in such a way that the entire traversal results in a `Maybe` without depending on `Monoid` magic?

Comment: @SaurabhNanda The "magic" is that the `Maybe Text` gets folded (for the sake of comparison, `["foo", "bar"] ^. traverse` results in `"foobar"`). If you prefer getting the `Maybe Text` rather than folding it, use `(^?)` instead of `(^.)`, as in the second and third variants in the answer. (Depending on the amount of magic you are okay with, you might see `foldOf` as an improvement over `(^.)` in this case with respect to explicitness.)

Comment: would you like to add `^?` to the answer? I'll mark it as correct.

Comment: @SaurabhNanda I added an extra paragraph highlighting the use of `(^?)`.

Comment: Some further explanation of "`view` specialised to `(->)`" might be useful for some... well me at least... or a link to the referenced docs.

Comment: @PaulGardiner I have added links to the docs; thanks for the suggestion. This is perhaps easier to appreciate in he other direction: if `foo` is a lens, or more generally a getter, from `s` to `a`, `(^.)` makes it possible to extract an `a` from an `s` value, so that `\s -> s ^. foo` is an `s -> a` function. `view` does pretty much the same thing, except that it generalises the result to an arbitrary `MonadReader` (that is, from `s -> a` to `MonadReader s m => m a`). See also [this other answer of mine](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66772811), which touches on this issue.

Comment: `^?` is nice and clean. The only unfortunate thing is that `lens` doesn't express *affine* traversals the way at least some profunctor lens formulations do. It would be nice to have a special operator that insists on its argument optic traversing at most one element, for clarity.