# What's the difference between view and use in lens?

Tags: haskell, haskell-lens, lenses

What's the difference between

```hs
view :: MonadReader s m => Getting a s a -> m a
```

and

```hs
use :: MonadState s m => Getting a s a -> m a
```

in [Control.Lens.Getter](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/lens-5.0.1/docs/Control-Lens-Getter.html)?

Comment: Do you understand the difference between `MonadReader` and `MonadState`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Taking a look at the type signatures, `view` takes a `MonadReader` (such as `ReaderT`) and `use` takes a `MonadState` (such as `StateT`). Now, `view` and `use` both have the same objective: extract a reasonable value from the thing we're looking at.

`MonadReader` represents read-only state. We can access the value within using [`ask`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/mtl-2.2.1/docs/Control-Monad-Reader.html#v:ask). `MonadState` represents read-write state, which can be retrieved with [`get`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/mtl-2.2.1/docs/Control-Monad-State-Lazy.html#v:get). So both `view` and `use` query the internal state of the monad given, but `view` calls `ask` whereas `use` calls `get`. Generally speaking, only one will be applicable to your situation.

A look at the source code for the two functions is not particularly enlightening unless you already understand how lenses are implemented (and if you do, then you probably understand the difference between `view` and `use`), so this is a good example of a situation where the type signatures can be much more enlightening than the code itself.

Comment: "only one will be applicable to your situation" -- I think this misses a crucial point. If only one applies, there would be no point of having both. We would only have the more general `view`, as well as `ask`, and we could forget `use`/`get`. IMO, the reason why we have both is that it is possible to have a `MonadReader s1` which is also `MonadState s2` (e.g. using `RWS`), and now we do need two operations for "reading the read-only state" and "reading the read-write state", hence the two lense-related operaitons.

Comment: Assuming I don't like the design pattern of `RWS`, or combining two pieces of state in the same monad stack without some sort of discriminating identification, would it make sense for `MonadState` to have been a subclass of `MonadReader`?

Comment: If you don't like `RWS` then sure i suppose. But I personally have found `RWS` incredibly useful on many occasions, when we have some top-level configuration environment (read-only) alongside some mutable program state (read-write), and there'd be no way for the two to coexist, in the same way that (as you've correctly pointed out) you can't easily have two `MonadState` instances in the same stack when using the mtl idiom.

Comment: @AriFordsham One complication is that `MonadReader` also has [`local`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/mtl-2.2.2/docs/Control-Monad-Reader.html#v:local) as a method, and `local` would be out of place in `MonadState`. While that issue might in principle be dodged by splitting `MonadReader` in two classes, Silvio Mayolo's objection would remain: it is useful to be able to handle a fixed environment and a changeable state separately on a single monad, and the subclass relationship would, as far as *mtl* is concerned, preclude that.

Answer (score 0):

A *lens* getter gives us a function from its source to its target:

```
(^.) :: s -> Getting a s a -> a

flip (^.) :: Getting a s a -> s -> a
```

Any function can be made into a `MonadReader` computation, with the argument type of the function as the environment type:

```
asks :: MonadReader s m => (s -> a) -> m a
```

That being so, `(^.)` can be generalised to any `MonadReader` through `asks`, giving rise to `view`:

```
view :: MonadReader s m => Getting a s a -> m a
view g = asks (\s -> s ^. g)
```

(The definitions I'm using here aren't literally the ones you will find in [the `Control.Lens.Getter` source](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/lens-5.0.1/docs/src/Control.Lens.Getter.html), but they are equivalent to them as far as results go.)

In a similar way, any function can be made into a `MonadState` computation that leaves the state unchanged, with the argument type of the function as the state type:

```
gets :: MonadState s m => (s -> a) -> m a
```

Accordingly, `(^.)` can also be generalised to any `MonadState` through `gets`, resulting in `use`:

```
use :: MonadReader s m => Getting a s a -> m a
use g = gets (\s -> s ^. g)
```

From another angle, `view` and `use` can be seen as variants of `asks` and `gets`, respectively, that take a getter as argument, rather than a function directly.

On a final note about `view`, functions themselves are instances of `MonadReader`. That being so, `view` can be used as a prefix/non-operator version of `(^.)`.